# How do I use the message module with the flag?

Tags: 8, rules, flags, message-subscribe

On Drupal 8 I installed the "Message" and "Flag" modules.

I created a flag "Report content" and I want a message to be sent to the site administrator as soon as a content is reported.

Messages will be displayed in a table view.

The "Report content" flag includes a "Pattern" field.

The message must contain the date of the flag, the author of the flag, the flagged node and the pattern of the flag.

For the flag no problem, but for the module "Message" it is a discovery.

After creating a message template "Reported Content", what should I do?

I read all the documentation and I can not.

I also installed the mudule "Message notify" and "Message UI".

Comment: Your question is, IMO, pretty much a duplicate of [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/194532/39516) ... and [it's accepted answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220124/39516) (disclosure: it's mine) explains how to get the job done ... in D7. To also use that solution to make it work for D8: [start here](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3616/39516) ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Thank you, I'll read all that. But the "Rules" module does not work on D8

Comment: Indeed, that's why I added the "start here"-link ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Ok, but what should I do on this page? Another question: if I understood correctly with the "Message", one can use "Rules" or templates in the theme (it amounts to the same thing)? So there is 2 possibility to run messages, templates (code) and rules (graph)